# writing "assertion" views - union of select count(*) subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I am not sure what would be an appropriate title for this question.

Anyway, I have a rather complex SQL schema and a number of views built on top of it.
To ensure that views are correct I maintain some "assertions", i.e. boolean expressions in SQL, expressed in terms of `COUNT(*)` and other aggregate functions that should be true.

To give an example, say I have two tables `table_a` and `table_b` and two very simple views on them than just reproduce them:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (foo VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE table_b (foo VARCHAR(50));
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_a AS SELECT * FROM table_a;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_b AS SELECT * FROM table_b;
```

Then two very simple assertions would be that the number of rows in `view_a` should equal those in `table_a`. And the same for `view_b` and `table_b` respectively.

I would then create the "assertions" view as:

```
CREATE VIEW ASSERTIONS AS
SELECT 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view_a) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a)=0) AS a
    ,
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view_b) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_b)=0) AS b
```

This produces:

```
select * from assertions;

a    |  b
-----------
true |  true
```

The problem with the above is that I would like the information to be present as different rows, and not as different columns, so that I could perhaps add a name or even description to every "assertion". Also, adding more assertions become cumbersome with the SQL I have now as they appear as new columns (instead of as new rows)

How do I write the above "assertions" VIEW so that I get:

```
 select * from assertions;

 description   | result
 ----------------------
 'blah blah a' | true
 'blah blah b' | true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just union individual `select`s:

```
CREATE VIEW ASSERTIONS AS
select 
    'blah blah a' as description, 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view_a) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_a)=0) AS result
union all
select 
    'blah blah b', 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM view_b) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_b)=0)
```

`union all` bypasses a (needless) `distinct` on the results, since you already know you'll be selecting distinct rows. You can also omit the column aliases on subsequent `select`s.